# Acessar o site via HTTPS - AWS

Tags: linux, amazon-aws, ssl, https

Estou com dúvidas para acessar o site usando o protocolo HTTPS para os domínios em minha hospedagem.

Subi uma instância Linux T2.micro zona São Paulo (Amazon ECS). Já fiz o procedimento para adquirir o certificado (ACM) e o status dele é 'Emitido'.
Também configurei o CloudFront e o status dele é 'Implantado' e habilitei o SSL do Apache2 (sudo a2ensite default-ssl). Porém, ao acessar o site utilizando o HTTPS, diz que o site não é seguro, fica com o HTTPS riscado em vermelho.

Nessa mesma instância possuo outros sites (domínios diferentes) e gostaria de habilitar o HTTPS para eles também.
O que está faltando ou o que estou fazendo de errado?
A maioria dos tutorias que encontrei são superficiais e não tem detalhes do passo-a-passo...

Abraços a todos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depois de várias tentativas e reconfigurações, o professor Francisco Edilton (Cloud Architect) descobriu o erro! Faltou fazer o apontamento do domínio para o Load Balancer. Substitui o apontamento do IP da instancia para o Load Balancer e sucesso!

Agradeço a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Recomendaria que você utilizasse o Letsencrypt ou CertBot para gerar certificados HTTPS. Para que você coloque em funcionamento o certificado, você deve usar dependendo do seu site, Apache ou Nginx para poder configurar adequadamente os certificados. Lembrando, que todas as configurações, visto que você está utilizando uma instância micro, devem ser realizada no terminal com comando sudo preferencialmente.

Comment: Olá Matheus, aprecio sua resposta! Gostaria de entender o motivo ou o que estou fazendo de errado, pois o certificado da AWS o site já possui, porém continua aparecendo como "não seguro".

Comment: mas esse seu certificado é direito da aws? Você não implantou no server? Pode dar mais detalhes?

Comment: É direto da AWS. Nao implementei no server.
Meus passos foram: Criar e habilitar/verificar um certificado no AWS Certificate Manager, habilitar o acesso SSL no servidor pelo comando 'a2ensite default-ssl', criar uma 'distribuição' no CloudFront e por último habilitar o LoadBalancer na instancia do meu servidor. 
Feito esses passos, atualmente o site entra com o HTTPS, porém o símbolo fica vermelho (do HTTPS no browser).